# Gulp task module export declaration

Tags: gulp, commonjs

A lot of examples of gulp setups are using the common JS pattern. Gulp tasks are defined follows:

**myGulpTask.js**

```
const gulp = require('gulp');

const paths = {
    src = './src',
    dest = './dest'
}

const myGulpTask = function() {

    return gulp.src(paths.srcFoo)
        .pipe() // do stuff
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dest));
}

module.exports = myGulpTask;
gulp.task('my-gulp-task', myGulpTask);
```

This allows you to use this gulp task using:

`$ npm run gulp myGulpTask`

But since the task is directly assigned, would it make sense to define the export as follows:

```
//...
const myGulpTask = module.exports = function() {

    return gulp.src(paths.srcFoo)
        .pipe() // do stuff
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dest))
}

gulp.task('my-gulp-task', myGulpTask);
//...
```

Maybe it's sweating the small stuff, or is there a difference in these two module declarations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference in either way, the first one is more friendly and easy to read.